# Error: “Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin” when using dataType text/html accessing a php file using JQuery's ajax method

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Why am i getting this error on chrome when using dataType text and html? It works if i echo a javascript and i set dataType to script? How do i echo back non-javascript data from a php file?

```
    client side:

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8888/test.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
    }

    php file (test.php):

    <?php
    echo "Hello";
     ?>php file (test.php):
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a cross-domain request issue (quite possibly because your client-side script isn't served from http://localhost:8888/).

By setting `dataType` to `script` you're enabling a type of request that handles cross-domain requests by injecting a `<script/>` tag into the page DOM. The code that implements this is [on GitHub here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js#L34).

You need to either:

- Resolve the [cross-domain request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests) issue by serving your client-side script from the same host & port as your PHP.
- Change your script to return [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: Oh I see. So i can't send html and text as cross-domain but i can do script and jsonp?

Comment: JSONP is a work around to allow you to do cross-domain requests. It works through a loophole in same-origin security model. By bypassing that security though you are no longer protected by it, so if you want to use JSONP, make sure you understand the risks first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP